# Align some text between two html.actionlinks

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I have been trying to place a "|" between two actionlinks but it just goes out of the place.Is there a way I can align them just like in plain html page.

```
@Html.ActionLink(....)
|
@Html.ActionLink(....)
```

but doesnt align properly.Am i missing some simple rule?

I am new to MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `span` tag like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(....)
<span> | </span>
@Html.ActionLink(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it add non-breakable space between the ActionLinks and Pipe symbols to keep them inline. if you need more space between add more

```
@Html.ActionLink(....)
&nbsp;|&nbsp;
@Html.ActionLink(....)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet also will help

```html
  <span><a href="http://google.com">Test1</a></span>
  <span>|</span>
  <span><a href="http://google.com">Test2</a></span>
```